# Numpy array to string for loading?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

The code below is generating a error. However when replacing data1 with a string the code works. Should I reformated data1 before I can import a file?

```
files = []
# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.txt' in file:
             files.append(os.path.join(r, file))
             #files.append(file)

i=0
while i < len(files):
    #print (files[i])
    i +=1

#input()


#Load Tradefile
data=numpy.genfromtxt(fname = files[0],dtype='str')

print ('loading csv file : ')
print (data[0])

#print (temp)
#Load CSV file
data1=data[0]

print (temp1)
#data1='D:/Synergy Development/AUDCAD/21032019/Synergy Exported Signals/AUDCAD_21032019-0001.csv'
contents=numpy.genfromtxt(fname=data1,delimiter =",", dtype='str',unpack=False)
```

Comment: Please clarify what output you expect the code to produce. Please also include the error so we can compare the error to the code.

Comment: Which line produced the error?  what error - full text!  If it's the one using `files[0]`, what is `files[0]` - not just what you think it should be.

Comment: If you have many arrays you need to save/load, it might be worth considering `numpy.save()`/`numpy.savez()`.

Comment: The issue is the difference in format of data1. If I use :data1='D:/Synergy Development/AUDCAD/21032019/Synergy Exported Signals/AUDCAD_21032019-0001.csv'. The code works fine. However when I get the filename of files[0] then I get a error. Contents of files[0] ['C:\\Synergy_Signals\\AUDCAD\\03052019\\Synergy' 'Exported'
 'Signals\\AUDCAD_03052019_All-0020.csv']

Comment: Do I need to reformat files[0] to some other format?